# Retrieve Document ID of document which is already uploaded in Template before sending email using docusign api

Tags: docusignapi

We have a situation, when a document is already uploaded in Template we need to get its Document Id for placing Sign here tab in particular document at code level. In local I can assign document id when reading the file from system. But once document is already in DocuSign template I am not able to get its Document ID. Request anyone to provide details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a call to `GET /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/templates/{templateId}/documents`
this will return a list of all documents in the template and each of them will include the documentID you need